# Prove the set $C$ is open set. By definition of ball.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<1 , |y|<1\}.$

 I want to prove that $C$ is an open set.

Suppose $(a,b) \in C$.

Let $r=\min\{1-a,1+a,1-b,1+b\}.$

We need show $B((a,b),r)\subset C.$

Let $(x,y)\in B((a,b),r).$  Then $d((x,y),(a,b)) \lt r$.

In this step I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think your $r$ needs to be in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: It depends on how you define $d(x,y)$.

Comment: True @TrevorNorton i go to edit tht

Comment: @copper.hat is with the usual metric $d_2$ in $\mathbb{R}\ ^2$

Comment: There are many usual metrics.

Comment: I suppose he is referring to the Euclidean Metric

Comment: @copper.hat the euclidean metric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $d(x,y) \ge \max(|x|,|y|)$ (the latter is another standard metric
on $\mathbb{R}^2$).

So, if $d((x,y),(a,b)) < r $, then $|x-a| < r$ and $|y-b| < r$.

We have $|x-a| <r$, or equivalently,
$-r < x-a < r$, adding $a$ gives $a-r < x < a+r$, then since
$r \le 1-a$ we have $x < 1$ and since $r < 1+a$ we have $-1 < a-r$ hence
$-1 < x < 1$.

The same sort of analysis applies to $|y-b|<r$ yielding $-1 < y <1$.

Hence $(x,y) \in C$.